# Which one is correct? Don’t we do as necessary as rigorous math?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

The mathematical statement $$\exists h\in \mathbb{R} \quad  \dfrac{1}{h}=5 $$ seems a mathematical statement that is true.

However, its negation $$\forall h\in \mathbb{R} \quad  \dfrac{1}{h}\neq 5$$ is not a mathematical statement, because it claims that $\displaystyle\frac10\ne5,$ which is nonsense since $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse.

Consequently, the two statements either are not negations of each other or are mathematically nonsense. Which is it?

And how do I formalise “there exists a real number whose multiplicative inverse is $5$” ?

Comment: *For this expression to be a mathematically meaningful sentence, we should be able to check it for every real number.* Some forms of intuitionism might interest you.

Comment: By saying “meaningful”, I meant nothing actually. I just meant that “For this expression to be a mathematical sentence, we should...”. So contrarily, I feel nothing about math. A sentence is either meaningful (i.e. we are allowed to write it) in math or not. For example, $1=0$ is a wrong mathematical sentence but $\dfrac{1}{0}=5$ is not even a mathematical sentence, i.e. mathematically meaningless.

Comment: $(\forall h\in \mathbb{R}) \;   \left(5h\neq1\right)$

Comment: Although $\frac 10$ may be non-sensical, $\frac 10 \ne 5$ so the statement is still true.

Comment: @Tavish No, an expression that is not well-formed has no truth value—from a formal standpoint, it's a nonsensical string of symbols with no meaning whatsoever, neither true nor false.

Comment: @DanielHast Really? It still feels unconvincing though, as if we suppose the statement isn’t true, then that would mean $\frac 10=5$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: It's not a *statement* in the formal logical sense at all—it's a nonsensical string of symbols with no meaning, from which we can derive no conclusions whatsoever. (That is, unless we resolve the issue by, say, interpreting division in the extended real numbers rather than the standard real numbers so we have a formal interpretation of $1/0$, but then there's no syntactic issue at all.)

Comment: @Tavish We didn’t define the object $\dfrac{1}{0}$. If you $\textbf{define}$ it to be equal to 7, then you can say that it is not equal to 5. But otherwise $\dfrac{1}{0}=5$ is mathematically the same as “rgjrhj=eghjy”. I mean we don’t know what is rgjrhy as we dont know what is $\dfrac{1}{0}$. Because we didn’t define them.

Comment: your statements are not well typed, that is the main issue!

Comment: um, it is actually true that $\frac{1}{0} \neq 5$. do not overthink this

Answer (score 10):

Assuming we interpret division to mean the usual notion of division in the real numbers, you're correct that the statement $(\exists h \in \mathbb{R})(1/h = 5)$ doesn't quite make sense, for the reason you stated. A more formal way of putting it is that $1/h = 5$ is not, in fact, a predicate with domain $\mathbb{R}$, so we can't quantify it over $\mathbb{R}$.

There are a few ways to correct this:

1. Rewrite the statement as $(\exists h \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})(1/h = 5)$ instead, so the domain matches the domain of division of real numbers.
2. Rewrite the statement as $(\exists h \in \mathbb{R})(1 = 5h)$, noting that $1/h = 5$ is equivalent to $1 = 5h$ for all $h \neq 0$, but the latter also makes sense (though it is false) for $h = 0$. I'd say this is the most straightforward way to formalize "there exists a real number whose multiplicative inverse is $5$".
3. Interpret the division symbol to mean division in the [real projective line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line) $\hat{\mathbb{R}}$, in which $1/0$ is a meaningful expression and is equal to $\infty$, a "point at infinity" that we add to the standard real numbers. With the division symbol interpreted in this way, $1/h = 5$ now makes sense for all $h \in \mathbb{R}$ (in fact, for all $h \in \hat{\mathbb{R}}$).

In practice, issues like this are often somewhat informally glossed over, because the intended meaning of the statement is clear and there's no ambiguity, as all these ways of resolving the formal syntactical issue lead to the same conclusion. But it's good to understand how a slightly informal notation like that can be correctly rewritten/reinterpreted to resolve any formal syntactical problems.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\exists h\in \mathbb{R} \quad  \dfrac{1}{h}=5 $$
> $$\forall h\in \mathbb{R} \quad  \dfrac{1}{h}\neq 5$$
> the two statements either are not negations of each other or are mathematically nonsense. Which is it?

The two sentences certainly are (logical) negations of each other, as they have opposite truth values whenever either has a truth value. The remaining question is whether in standard real analysis, these statements are **false** or **non-meaningful**?

- $\frac10=5$
- $\forall x{\in}\left\{0,\frac15\right\}\:\:\frac1x\ne5$
- the reciprocal function with domain $\mathbb R{\setminus}\{0\}$ is continuous at $0$

On the one hand, clearly none of them are true. On the other hand, it is semantically invalid to refer to undefined objects or make illegal attributions (like talking about a table's tail or $\frac1x$'s continuity at $0$). Probably, the former is usually more useful, whilst the latter applicable in more formal contexts.

> And how do I formalise “there exists a real number whose multiplicative inverse is $5$” ?

Directly (without reference to reciprocals): $$\exists h\in \mathbb{R} \quad  5h=1.$$